# The difference in usage amongst these verbs and adverbs?

Tags: глаголы, наречия

What is the difference of usage when these verbs, I frequently see them and cannot determine their specific usage respectively?

```
Использовать 

Использоваться

Пользоваться / воспользоваться / попользоваться 

Употреблять / Употребить
```

Also, I frequently see the use of these adverbs and cannot determine their usage, any examples will help.

```
В основном

Вообще

Вообще-то

В общее
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `использоваться` and `использовать` is that the first word is a reflexive verb ("to be used") and the second one is not ("to use").

`Использовать` and `пользоваться` and `воспользоваться` has similar meaning but vary in grammar. `пользоваться` has perfective aspect, `воспользоваться` has imperfective aspect, and `использовать` can be used in both aspects. Also, `использовать` requires винительный падеж, and two others require творительный падеж. Examples:

- Нужно использовать предмет. Нужно воспользоваться предметом. (imperfective aspect)
- Я использовал предмет. Я воспользовался предметом. (perfect aspect)

The word `попользоваться` is similar to `воспользоваться` or `использовать` but has additional meaning "to use and cease to use":

- Я попользовался книгой - I have used the book and ceased to use it.

`Употреблять` and `употребить` are similar to `пользоваться` and `воспользоваться` but have another meaning "to take, consume" (drinks, food, drugs).

---

`В основном` - in principle, mainly, largely, basically:

- `Играли не все – то шестеро, то семеро, остальные только глазели, болея в основном за Вадика.`  - `Most of them supported Vadik.`
- `Ему просто здесь нечего делать, потому что принцы в основном занимаются охотой на оленей.` - `Most of princes hunts cervids.` Or: `Princes hunts cervids most of the time.`

`Вообще` - generally or on the whole:

- `Этот человек вообще необщителен.` - `This man is always unsociable.`
- `Я говорю о людях вообще, а не о тебе.` - `I'm telling about people as a whole, not about you alone.`

`Вообще` and `вообще-то` can be used in oppositions:

- `Над ним всегда смеются, хотя вообще он прав.` - `They are always laughing at him, although he is right.`
- `Над ним всегда смеются, хотя, вообще-то, он прав.`

`В общее` has no special meaning and cannot be used without a noun: `в общее дело` - `in the general work`.

Answer (score 0):

попользоваться also has the colloquial meaning of "borrowed without owner's permission or even knowledge" as in "Саша попользовался Юриной теннисной ракеткой".

Answer (score 0):

(If 12 months later is not too late...) Per what Pavel indicates above in his examples, the use of "Вообще - generally or on the whole" is also extensively used in conversational speech, often to emphasize a point, as in:

"И **вообще**, в городе слишком много горя и переживаний."

"Зачем тогда **вообще** подходить к человеку и начинать с ним говорить?"

One can really feel the emphasis in the statement when вообще is used.